# Strange CSS syntax

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have inherited some code which was written about 7-8 years ago.
The code contains some HTML with inline css.

I found something like this-

```
<span style="color='red'">Hello World</span>
```

Please Notice the `=` sign instead of the `:` sign in the style attribute.

Has anybody seen this before ? Is it to be considered Correct ?
Why would someone do such a thing ...?

It works for IE 6 and 7

I don't want it, but to afraid of the sequences if I will change it

Comment: It cannot be considered correct with respect to the syntax of the CSS. May be it would have been written by mistake.

Comment: Thanks @AmGates, that's what I thought, yet it works...

Comment: It's not "correct" CSS, however IE 6 and 7 are magical entities and a lot of things work that aren't supposed to and don't work that are supposed to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Has anybody seen this before?

Yes

> Is it to be considered Correct ?

No

> Why would someone do such a thing ...?

By error

> It works for IE 6 and 7

Different browsers will recover from different errors. It generally isn't a good idea to depend on it.

> I don't want it, but to afraid of the sequences if I will change it

I don't know the context, but it should be fine to change it.

Occasionally this type of error recovery will be exploited to provide CSS to only specific browsers (usually to compensate for *other* bugs) but it is unlikely that any part of the design is *depending* on the colour applying only in IE 6/7.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct of course; it violates basic CSS [declaration syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#declaration).

Old versions of IE support many nonstandard syntax features, thought only in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). Such support is forbidden in CSS specifications: they have [error handling rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors) that require that constructs like `color='red'` be ignored.

Generally, code written 7–8 years ago should be left untouched, or, if changes are needed, changed minimalistically. In this case, the code has some effect on some very old browsers, no effect on others. If there is strong evidence that it is important to make the code work the intended way, you can change it, but then you need to consider the page or site as a whole and check what other things are affected.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that it's a syntactic error.

It should be:

```
<span style="color:red;">Hello World</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong syntax and the style would not work see here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EWrn/)

right sytax is

```
<span style="color:red;">Hello World</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works on IE6 and IE7, but on modern browsers like chrome, firefox it won't work... i would suggest to stick with the new version. i.e. 
    `<span style="color:red;">hello</span>`

Answer (score 0):

It is most definitely not correct, however many things work in IE6 and 7 that aren't supposed to and don't work that are supposed to.

I imagine what happened was someone came along and decided to "fix" the old school way of doing things:

```
<span color='red'>Hello World</span>
```

And surrounded the `color` attribute in `style=""`.

Needless to say, you shouldn't worry about ramifications provided the text is supposed to be red. `style="color:red;"` will work in any browser today.

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious mistake made by a previous developer. Change it to:

```
<span style="color:red;">Hello World</span>
```

You will have no issues changing it to this, so your worries should be settled on that.

The reason it may have worked, is because browsers handle improper markup in their own way. Have you noticed that unlike programming languages which error and therefore 'break', HTML is rendered as best as the browser can make it, regardless of what the developer has done?

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 0):

This is syntactically incorrect

It's meant to be

```
<span style="color:red;">Hello World</span>
```